# Java Swing for emulation

Tags: java, swing, emulation

I am planning to create a GUI for an emulation process using Java Swing.
I would like to kindly ask if anyone could provide me some basic information about the technologies that I may need for the development of Java applications which handle emulation processes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to emulate?

Comment: I don't know yet as it is a future assignment, I guess a Commodore 64. I need to provide a window and some control such as the volume...

Comment: It's nice to see that you are thinking ahead but trying to solve a problem whose nature you do not know isn't exactly the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

You may find JPC interesting.  It emulates a whole pc in Java.

http://jpc.sourceforge.net/home_home.html

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha thanks. Note that this is a community effort - next time feel free to fix dead links